Is there a way on Linux for a shared library to dynamically choose how to link to its dependency?
Situation:
There is a library A with a dependency on library B. However, B is often provided by the system and some program that may want to link with A may be depending on the system-provided library.
A is dependent on a specific version of B and as such is bundled with it, but any newer version of B should work fine due to compatibility guarantees provided by B.
Problem:
Is it possible for A to dynamically select which B it is linked against (the system provided one or the bundled one), assuming there is a way to determine which one is "newer"?
Note, that it should ideally be as transparent for "consumers" of A as possible, i.e. they shouldn't try to preload appropriate version of B themselves and just link with A. Also A uses symbols from B to initialize its own global variables.
I.e. what I want to effectively achieve is for dynamic linker, when it loads library A and tries to satisfy its dependencies, to choose the newer of (bundled B|system B) if both exist.

If, at the time that the program was started, the environment
variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH was defined to contain a colon-
separated list of directories, then these are searched.
Check dlopen and ldd man pages.

There is no program, just shared libraries. Their dependencies should be opaque to any binary that tries to link them. "google it" is not an answer (for SO).
